# Macro in PowerPoint which links to data stored in an Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

I have an Excel Spreadsheet (let's say objectdata.xls) which is used to set the widths/lengths of different rectangles. The spreadsheet therefore has 3 columns:

Object Name
Object Width 
Object Length

There are approx 100 rectangles defined in the Spreadsheet

What i am try to do is run a macro in a PowerPoint (PP) which will read the data from the Spreadsheet (ideally this info should be stored external to the PP file but if need be it could be a linked or embedded file within PP) and then update the size of the rectangle shapes that I have included in the PP file.

E.g. on slide one, the macro reads row 1 in the spreadhseet and sees that the object width is 5 and length is 10, and so updates the size of the rectangle shape in the PP.

Can anyone tell me if this can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: Are all the rectangles on different slides?

Answer (score 1):

Use GetExcelData to do the work; it calls GetExcel

```
Function GetExcel() As Object
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : GetExcel
' Author    : Naresh Nichani / Steve Rindsberg
' Purpose   :
'               Check if an instance of Excel is running. If so obtain a reference to the running Excel application
'               Otherwise Create a new instance of Excel and assign the XL application reference to oXLApp object
' SR        :   Modified 2010-02-23 to ALWAYS create a new instance rather than using an existing one, so when we
'           :   close the one we open, we don't wack the user's other instances of Excel if any
' Params    :   None
' Returns   :   An Excel Application object on success, Nothing on failure
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   On Error GoTo GetExcel_ErrorHandler

    On Error Resume Next
    Err.Number = 0

    Dim oXLAPP As Object

' Comment out the following bits to force a new instance of Excel
' and leave any existing instances alone
'    Set oXLApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
'    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
'        Err.Number = 0
        Set oXLAPP = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            'MsgBox "Unable to start Excel.", vbInformation, "Start Excel"
            Exit Function
        End If
'    End If

   On Error GoTo GetExcel_ErrorHandler

    If Not oXLAPP Is Nothing Then
        Set GetExcel = oXLAPP
    Else
        [MASTTBAR].rnrErrLog "modExcel:GetExcel - unable to invoke Excel instance"
    End If

    Set oXLAPP = Nothing

    Exit Function

NormalExit:
   On Error GoTo 0
   Exit Function

GetExcel_ErrorHandler:
    Resume NormalExit
End Function

Function GetExcelData(sFilename As String, _
    Optional lWorksheetIndex As Long = 1, _
    Optional sWorksheetName As String = "") As Variant
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Purpose   : Gets the "active" data from the file/worksheet specified

    Dim oXLAPP As Object
    Dim oxlWB As Object
    Dim oxlRange As Object

    Dim x As Long
    Dim y As Long
    Dim sMsg As String

    Dim lVisibleRowCount As Long
    Dim lVisibleColCount As Long

    Dim aData() As String

   On Error GoTo GetExcelData_ErrorHandler

    Set oXLAPP = GetExcel()
    If oXLAPP Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' open the workbook read-only
    Set oxlWB = oXLAPP.Workbooks.Open(sFilename, , True)
    If oxlWB Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    If Len(sWorksheetName) > 0 Then
        Set oxlRange = GetUsedRange(oxlWB.Worksheets(sWorksheetName))
    Else
        Set oxlRange = GetUsedRange(oxlWB.Worksheets(lWorksheetIndex))
    End If

    If oxlRange Is Nothing Then
        Exit Function
    End If

    ' Get a count of visible rows/columns (ignore hidden rows/cols)
    For x = 1 To oxlRange.Rows.Count
        If Not oxlRange.Rows(x).Hidden Then
            lVisibleRowCount = lVisibleRowCount + 1
        End If
    Next    ' row

    For y = 1 To oxlRange.Columns.Count
        If Not oxlRange.Columns(y).Hidden Then
            lVisibleColCount = lVisibleColCount + 1
        End If
    Next

    ReDim aData(1 To lVisibleRowCount, 1 To lVisibleColCount)

    lVisibleRowCount = 0
    For x = 1 To oxlRange.Rows.Count
        If Not oxlRange.Rows(x).Hidden Then
            lVisibleRowCount = lVisibleRowCount + 1
            lVisibleColCount = 0
            For y = 1 To oxlRange.Columns.Count
                If Not oxlRange.Columns(y).Hidden Then
                    lVisibleColCount = lVisibleColCount + 1
                    aData(lVisibleRowCount, lVisibleColCount) = oxlRange.Cells(x, y).Text
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next

    ' return data in array
    GetExcelData = aData

NormalExit:
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Close the workbook
    If Not oxlWB Is Nothing Then
        oXLAPP.DisplayAlerts = False
        oxlWB.Close
        oXLAPP.DisplayAlerts = True
    End If

    'To Close XL application
    If Not oXLAPP Is Nothing Then
        oXLAPP.Quit
    End If

    'Set the XL Application and XL Workbook objects to Nothing
    Set oxlRange = Nothing
    Set oxlWB = Nothing
    Set oXLAPP = Nothing

    Exit Function

GetExcelData_ErrorHandler:
    Resume NormalExit

End Function
```

> Blockquote
>   Blockquote`enter code here`

Comment: This GetUsedRange function show to me as not defined. I changed the code to: oxlWB.Worksheets(sWorksheetName).UsedRange and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can certainly be done. It takes a bit more code than I have at the tip of my fingers and you'd need to adapt whatever I posted.  But have a look here for examples you can start with. These point to the PowerPoint FAQ site that I maintain.  No charge for anything.

Controlling Office Applications from PowerPoint (by Naresh Nichani and Brian Reilly)
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00795.htm

Automate Excel from PowerPoint. Automate PowerPoint from Excel. And so on.
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00368.htm

I'd probably do this by opening the excel file, reading the contents into an array, then using the data from the array to do the actual work in PPT.

If you need help with the PPT part, let us know.  It'd mostly be a matter of writing a function like [aircode]:

```
Sub SetRectangleSize ( sRectangleName as string, sngWidth as Single, sngHeight as Single)
  Dim oShp as Shape
  Set oShp = GetShapeNamed(sRectangleName, lSlideIndex)
  If Not oShp is Nothing Then
    With oShp
        .Width = sngWidth
        .Height = sngHeight
    End With
  End If
End Sub
```

And

```
Function GetShapeNamed(sName as String, lSlideIndex as Long) as Shape
  On Error Resume Next
  Set GetShapeNamed = ActivePresentation.Slides(lSlideIndex).Shapes(sName)
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
     ' no shape by that name on the slide; return null
     Set GetShapeNamed = Nothing
  End If
End Function
```

Incidentally, I would consider using tags to identify the rectangles rather than shape names (which tend to be less reliable).

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I will look over this and attempt to get it working and come back if I have any further questions.
Much much much appreciated!!!

Comment: Hi, 
I've had a chance now to go through this and was just wondering if you could give me some code for opening the excel file and reading the contents into an array.
I think that's the bit im stuck on. Again, thanks so much - very helpful.

Comment: See the new answer I posted earlier.